# How to read if an oil satisifies the motor reqiurments and can it vary a bit?

Tags: oil

I'm reading about how to change oil on a honda cbr 500 ra 2016 model. According to the manual, this is the recommendations:

[image]

I already have **Motul 5000 4T 10w-40 HC-Tech** in stock. Can I use that? It seems to check all the standards but it is 10w-40 instead of 10w-30.

Will it be okay or do you need to be super sharp about these requirements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to what Honda wants, this oil is not what you should be using. A couple of things you didn't mention from the clip in your question are posted here:

[image]

On the right side, it shows the JASO T 903 standard required. Your bike requires a JASO MA standard. The Motul oil meets an MA2 standard, which is *very narrow* and therefore is not a match to what your bike requires.

[image]

MA1 and MA2 only meet a very narrow performance class, where as MA is very broad. This means the Motul oil is most likely outside of the performance range parameters required by Honda.

[image]

Besides this being off, the weight of the oil is very important. Bearing clearances are built to require the specified oil weight. If you use weight which is different, you are most likely not doing your engine any favors.

Considering the Motul does not meet the performance standard and the weight is off, you need to pass on this oil and find something which is what Honda wants you to put in there by meeting the specifications.